# Extracting numbers from string that allows for word variation

Tags: r, regex, string, text

I have already asked a version of this in:

[Extracting Numbers Based On the Following Term in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120014/extracting-numbers-based-on-the-following-term-in-a-string):

I have some messy data in which I need to extract sentencing length from a string variable with no real uniform input. I would need the number of months or days that a person was sentenced to either 'jail' or 'prison' in a `months` and `days` variable while ignoring any other numbers in the string (days to community service, for example).

So if I have the data

```
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(text=c("Person 1: $1000 fine, 31 months jail", 
                        "Person 2: $500 fine, 45 days jail",
                        "Person 3: 35 dys jail",
                        "Person 4: 14 mnths prison, 30 days community release"))
data


                                                   text
1:                 Person 1: $1000 fine, 31 months jail
2:                    Person 2: $500 fine, 45 days jail
3:                                Person 3: 35 dys jail
4: Person 4: 14 mnths prison, 30 days community release
```

I would need to extrapolate the months and days information to form:

```
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(text=c("Person 1: $1000 fine, 31 months jail", 
                        "Person 2: $500 fine, 45 days jail",
                        "Person 3: 35 dys jail",
                        "Person 4: 14 mnths prison, 30 days community release"), 
                 months=c("31","","","14"), 
                 days=c("","45","35",""))
data

                                                   text months days
1:                 Person 1: $1000 fine, 31 months jail     31     
2:                    Person 2: $500 fine, 45 days jail          45
3:                                Person 3: 35 dys jail          35
4: Person 4: 14 mnths prison, 30 days community release     14
```

I have been trying to figure this out with `library(qdap)` and tweaking the following code from my previous question:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- dplyr::mutate(data,
                      months = stringr::str_extract(text, "\\d+(?=\\s*months*)"),
                      days = stringr::str_extract(text, "\\d+(?=\\s*days*)"))
```

However, nothing I have done work. Admittedly, text analysis is a weak point and I have learned quickly that substitutting the above code with something like `str_extract(text, "\\d+(?=\\s*days|dys* jail|prison)")` does nothing.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Trying to figure out a way to code this so I am not forced to hand code thousands of observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::extract` to match a number which is followed by a word starting with `"m"` or `"d"` which is then followed by either jail or prison.

```
tidyr::extract(data, text, into = c("months", "days"), 
   regex = ".*?(\\d+)\\sm.*\\s(?=jail|prison)|.*?(\\d+)\\sd.*\\s(?=jail|prison)", 
   remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

#                                                   text months days
#1:                 Person 1: $1000 fine, 31 months jail     31   NA
#2:                    Person 2: $500 fine, 45 days jail     NA   45
#3:                                Person 3: 35 dys jail     NA   35
#4: Person 4: 14 mnths prison, 30 days community release     14   NA
```

We can also combine the pattern together and make it shorter but since we want two different columns with `"month"` and `"days"` information I have repeated the pattern with `"|"`.

---

As @thelatemail suggested base R version with `strcapture` would be

```
strcapture(".*?(\\d+)\\sm.*\\s(?=jail|prison)|.*?(\\d+)\\sd.*\\s(?=jail|prison)", 
            data$text, proto=list(months=1L,days=1L), perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice. Base R `strcapture` translation - `strcapture(pattern = regex, data$text, proto=list(months=1L,days=1L), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: This worked! I cannot thank you enough, I was staring down the barrel of really tedious line by line manual coding. Life saver.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `stringr::str_match` and just the first letter of days/dys or months/mnths...

```
data <- mutate(data,
               months = as.numeric(str_match(text, "(\\d+)\\s*m")[,2]),                   
               days = as.numeric(str_match(text, "(\\d+)\\s*d")[,2]))
```